# RFID card identification

Tags: delphi, rfid

I am looking for some libraries in delphi to programming and reading from RFID cards. today I use normal Mifare 1k cards, and use a simple library to read the cards UID, but I would like to do more with these cards, like storing and reading from theire memory.

today my development uses PCSCconnector.pas library in delphi (PC/SC Interface component)

I am not sure if this is capable of doing anything more advanced other than just send code to return the UID number of my cards ?

if not, what else is there out there who can be used?

in a second note, can someone push me in the right direction on how to identify card types?. what kind of RFID card I am holding, what are the parameters, mifare 1k. 5k? java card etc etc ?

Comment: No idea, but a +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: any software that can help identify as well would be nice, I heard about something for Linux, but I cannot remember what the name was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but a few notes and hints:

The problem with Mifare 1k (all Mifare Classic cards, not DESFire, Ultralight etc.) is that they are proprietary. Reading the UID is a standard function, supported by all ISO14443-compliant readers. To read/write data, you need to have a reader with Mifare (classic) support.

This raises the question on what kind of reader you are using?

The protocol and algorithms were reverse-engineered, but NXP does not license the crypto algorithm (crypto-1) - means any open source library doing so (there might be some) is probably not legal.

Documentation for all other NXP Mifare cards is only available under NDA.

EDIT:

SpringCard does have a lot of diagnostic software tools available on their website as well as a lot of other PC/SC-related resources. I think it is mainly C++/C#-focused.

http://www.springcard.com/solutions/pcsc.html

PC/SC Diag for example is quite handy for some quick tests on a card.

Comment: Interresting, I have actually been in contact with them before regarding a "crazywriter" I might dig alittle deeper into this one

Comment: Just to add something regarding card identification. Your reader might provide functions for that. Besides that, you can query the (emulated) ATR string - but that's not always easy to decode. The reader manual should also document that.

Comment: Thanks!, yes I have used an ATR code to return the UID, for normal mifare cards, but so far that's all I have been able to do, Tomorrow I get an EM reader, but i guess that has a complete different story :)